# Finding filenames with numbers in a range: is eval find ... "prefix_{$nr1..$nr2}_suffix" workable?

Tags: bash, find, brace-expansion

I am trying to use find in combination with a brace expansion and eval to find a number of files in subfolders. When I do this:

```
nr1=1001
nr2=1500
eval ls abc*_{$nr1..$nr2}*
```

It works as I would expect it to. However, when I try something like this:

```
eval find path/to/folder -name "abc*_{$nr1..$nr2}*"
```

I get the error message:

```
find: paths must precede expression: abc*_{1001..1500}*
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

I have tried different combinations with and without eval and nothing seems to work. Basically I need the find command to work with a brace expansion where variables are used and other metacharacters in the filename. I don't necessarily need to use eval though and I must admit that I do not fully understand it.

Comment: with `find`  you can do `-name "*pat1" -o -name "*pat2"` ... so on

Comment: `-name` takes a *single* pattern, and does not support brace expansion. Using `eval`, the *best* case scenario is that you end up with a command like `find /path -name abc_1001* abc_1002* ...`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `eval` is fault-prone, and that includes introducing security vulnerabilities when processing files with names chosen by others. [Don't do it](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). (Beyond that general admonition -- `foo{1..3}` expands to three separate arguments to the command being run, `foo1`, `foo2`, and `foo3`; putting 500 separate arguments on a `find` command line after `-name` is just as unworkable as it sounds; thus, you can't use that syntax in an argument passed to `find -name` even *without* `eval`).

A non-`eval`-based equivalent to your first command is:

```
args=( )
for ((i=nr1; i<=nr2; i++)); do
  args+=( abc*_"$i"* )
done
ls "${args[@]}"
```

For the second command, you'd end up with something closer to:

```
find_args=( )
for ((i=nr1; i<=nr2; i++)); do
  find_args+=( -name "abc*_${i}*" -o )
done
find path/to/folder '(' "${find_args[@]}" -false ')' -print
```

Note that the `-false` is there to fill in the right-hand side of the last `-o` in the stream of `-name foo -o name bar -o name baz` arguments stored in the `find_args` array.

---

However, in both these cases you run the risk of running out of space on your command line for large ranges (a risk you ran with the original code as well!). I would suggest filtering for the numeric range **after** running the `find` operation:

```
digits_re='_([[:digit:]]+)([^[:digit:]]|$)'
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  dirname=${filename%/*}
  basename=${filename##*/}
  if [[ $basename =~ $digits_re ]]; then
    number=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    if (( number >= nr1 && number <= nr2 )); then
      printf '%q\n' "$filename"  # for human consumption
      # use '%s\0' instead for a NUL-delimited stream for programmatic use.
    fi
  fi
done < <(find path/to/folder -name 'abc*_[[:digit:]]*' -print0)
```

Comment: Thank you, the second option should work as the output from find is stored in a variable with $().

Comment: Using `$()` to capture the output from `find` is actually not reasonable and safe. The domain of information `$()` can capture matches the domain of characters in possible filenames, so you can't possibly be sure that what you **think** is the delimiter between two names is such in fact.

Comment: Consider the file created with `touch $'foo\nbar'` -- you can't tell if the newline means that `bar` is a whole different filename, or if it's part of the name of the same file.

Comment: @longibongi, ...so, the **correct** way to retrieve a list of files from `find` is to emit them with `-print0`, and then either read them with a `while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do array+=( "$filename" ); done`-style loop or, in a new enough bash, to use `mapfile -0` or `readarray -0`.

Comment: @longibongi, ...and, as mentioned in the answer, the second option will only work for ranges of up to a certain size, since there are only so many arguments that will fit on a single `find` command's invocation (the details depend on your OS -- the space that both environment variables and command-line arguments need to fit into is typically between 64k and 128kb of memory on modern operating systems).